# H2 tables not showing up in IntelliJ for Jhipster generated project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, jhipster

So I generated a new Spring boot application using jhipster. Upon navigating to the H2 console, the following information is shown.

[image]

I am able to login, and I can verify tables exist.
[image]

Next, I copy the link, `jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/ikdoemee` and try to connect to the H2 database using IntelliJ which shows `successful`.
[image]

However, the IntelliJ database view isn't showing any tables.
[image]

I tried adding the following parameters to my JDBC url, but no tables show up.

```
jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/ikdoemee;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 ;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
```

Why am I unable to get my tables visible in IntelliJ?

My .h2.server.properties is

```
#H2 Server Properties
0=JHipster H2 (Disk)|org.h2.Driver|jdbc\:h2\:file\:./target/h2db/db/ikdoemee|ikdoemee
webAllowOthers=true
webPort=8082
webSSL=false
```

EDIT: My target folder:
[image]

Comment: the path to the H2 database is a relative path. try to put in an absolute path  in the idea config page.

Comment: I am able to connect to my database using the H2 console based on the absolute path `jdbc:h2:file:/Users/wvanvlaenderen/Workspace/ikdoemee/target/h2db/db/ikdoemee` and tables do show up. In IntelliJ I am unable to connect using this URL. However when I add the `.mv.db` extension `jdbc:h2:file:/Users/wvanvlaenderen/Workspace/ikdoemee/target/h2db/db/ikdoemee.mv.db` I am able to connect using IntelliJ but no tables show up.

Comment: have you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue I installed Buddy JPA plugin.
It created profile automatically and I compared it with mine.
the difference was in parameter **DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE**
I tried it with manually created profile and it works as well.
The result link is:

```
jdbc:h2:file:./work/h2db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate h2 "Automatic Mixed Mode" by changing the spring.datasource.url of the application-dev.yml file. 
example URL: `jdbc:h2:./target/h2db/db/'PROJECTNAME';AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`

The URL for the connection to the h2 database should look like that:

```
jdbc:h2:/home/'USERNAME'/IdeaProjects/'PROJECT'/target/h2db/db/'PROJECTNAME';AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
```

if that doesn't work try also to delete the target folder and refresh the h2 connection

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me at the moment is to put the **direct path** to the file in Path field without extension.
After that I could see my tables in IDEA.

[click to preview settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FyBd.png)

**Note:**

Don't forget to also add parameter `AUTO_SERVER=TRUE` to `datasource.url`, as pointed out by [@Unknown_Energy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2585133/unknown-energy).

My apps versions:

- Idea 2018.3.5 UE
- h2 1.4.197
- h2 base name: demo.mv.db

this bug is related to these issues:

- [Data Source detection](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4314?p=IDEA-162549)
- [Intellij IDEA and H2 DB file recognition problem](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203527130-Intellij-IDEA-and-H2-DB-file-recognition-problem)

Answer (score 0):

When running the application, the log will show something like
`n.w.config.DatabaseConfiguration 1: H2 database is available on port 18080.`
Then change Connection Type to Remote and port to the port just showed,
append the db file location to the url (with out extension) just like `./build/h2db/db/projectname`, User will be the ProjectName.

The final url will like jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:18080/./build/h2db/db/projectname

This worked for me, I'm not a English native speaker, sorry for my poor English.